# sympy.subs cannot substituting a point to array

Tags: python, math, sympy

```
import sympy
import numpy
from sympy import ordered, Matrix
x1,x2=sympy.symbols('x1 x2')
f=x1**2-x1*x2-4*x1+x2**2-x2
X0=numpy.array([[1],[1]])
v = list(ordered(f.free_symbols))
gradient = lambda f, v: Matrix([f]).jacobian(v)
gradf=sympy.transpose(gradient(f, v))
gradfx0=(gradf.subs([(x1, X0[0]), (x2, X0[1])]))
print(gradfx0)
```

I want to calculate the gradient of two variable function in a point in `python`. I define the function and I find the gradient vector of function (`grad`). Now when I try to substituting `X0` to `grad`, the result is

`Matrix([[2*x1 - x2 - 4], [-x1 + 2*x2 - 1]])`.

I want the result should be

`Matrix([[-3], [0]]).`

How to substituting a point to sympy array?

Comment: Newlines and whitespace are free. Please be generous with them in your code. Please avoid using `lambda` for a named function. Prefer `def` instead.

Comment: You mention a variable named `grad`, but there is no variable with that name in your code. There is a `gradient` and a `gradf` and a `gradfx0`.

Comment: Actually, if you just replace `X0=numpy.array([[1],[1]])` with `X0=numpy.array([1,1])` in your code, then you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Or alternatively, replace `gradfx0=(gradf.subs([(x1, X0[0]), (x2, X0[1])]))` with `gradfx0=(gradf.subs([(x1, X0[0,0]), (x2, X0[1,0])]))`

Comment: So the mistake in your code was that when you do `gradfx0=(gradf.subs([(x1, X0[0]), (x2, X0[1])]))`, the values you're giving to `subs` are not `(x1, 1)` and `(x2, 1)`, but instead `(x1, [1])` and `(x2, [1])`, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Or perhaps simpler alternative: replace `gradfx0 = ...` with `gradfx0 = gradf.subs(zip((x1,x2), X0[:,0]))`

Comment: Unless you are using `lambdify`, using `numpy` arrays with sympy is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`.subs`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) and [`derive_by_array`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html#derivatives-by-array):

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.tensor.array import derive_by_array

x1, x2 = symbols('x1 x2')
f = x1 ** 2 - x1 * x2 + x2 ** 2 - 4 * x1 - x2

grad = derive_by_array(f, (x1, x2))
#    = [2*x1 - x2 - 4, -x1 + 2*x2 - 1]

gradx0 = grad.subs({x1: 1, x2: 1})
#      = [-3, 0]
```

If you want to call your point `x0` first, then use variable `x0`:

```py
x0 = (1, 1)
gradx0 = grad.subs(zip((x1,x2), x0))
#      = [-3, 0]
```